# ¿Como controlar un grupo de controles en C# (Windwos Forms)?

Tags: c#

Me gustaría saber como puedo controlar cada grupo de colores (R, G, B) haciendo que cambiando el valor de un control como ScrollBar se cambia también el valor de Slider y DecimalUpDown.
Lo he hecho pero requiere escribir muchas lineas de código y me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de optimizarlo.

Gracias! 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    private void scR_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        slR.Value = scR.Value;
    }
    private void slR_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        scR.Value = slR.Value;
    }
    private void dcR_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {

    }

    #endregion
    #region GREEN
    private void dcG_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {

    }
    private void scG_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        slG.Value = scG.Value;
    }

    private void slG_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        scG.Value = slG.Value;
    }
    #endregion
    #region BLUE
    private void slB_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        scB.Value = slB.Value;
    }
    private void scB_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        slB.Value = scB.Value;
    }
    private void dcB_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {

    }
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma mas corta que conozco es utilizar el patrón MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel), de otra forma, al menos en winforms, no te podrás quitar de encima las líneas de código.

Aquí un pequeño ejemplo, por si te interesa implementarlo:

Creas una clase que contendrá los 4 valores, esta debe implementar la interfaz INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public class ColorData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int a;
    public int A
    {
        get { return a; }
        set
        {
            a = value;
            PropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("A"));
        }
    }

    private int r;
    public int R
    {
        get { return r; }
        set
        {
            r = value;
            PropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("R"));
        }
    }

    private int g;
    public int G
    {
        get { return g; }
        set
        {
            g = value;
            PropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("G"));
        }
    }

    private int b;
    public int B
    {
        get { return b; }
        set
        {
            b = value;
            PropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("B"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void PropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

}
```

Y en el contructor de tu formulario:
    // Inicializas una variable que va a contener los datos
    ColorData colorData = new ColorData ();
    // y a cada control le haces un binding de la propiedad que quieres que cambie automáticamente con el valor que le toca en la clase
    // por ejemplo, "Value" es la propiedad Value de los controles slR, slG y slB,
    slR.DataBindings.Add("Value", colorData, "R");
    slG.DataBindings.Add("Value", colorData, "G");
    slB.DataBindings.Add("Value", colorData, "B");

```
// si quieres inicializar valores:  
colorData.A = 0; 
colorData.R = 10;
colorData.G = 10;
colorData.B = 10;
```

En WPF es mas fácil pues existe el binding entre controles (le asignas el valor de otro control a un control y los cambios se reflejan automáticamente), si tu aplicación no es muy grande, igual y te conviene mas cambiar a WPF.